# Ionic - Runtime Error: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this very basic project:

https://github.com/napolev/ionic-start

which is basically the `Ionic` starter project:

```
// https://ionicframework.com/getting-started
$ ionic start ionic-start tabs
```

I added the following two files:

**/src/extras/social-media.ts**

```
import * as Promise from 'bluebird';
import { User } from './user';

export var LoginPromise = function(service): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve('Will Smith');
        }, 2000)
    });
};

//*/ IF I COMMENT THIS BLOCK OUT, THERE IS NO ERROR
// this function is not used by this project
// but for some specific reasons it is required to be here
// this code is a simplification of a bigger project
export var callMeIfYouNeedMe = function(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            console.log(user);
            resolve(user);
        });
    });
}
// END OF BLOCK */
```

**/src/extras/user.ts**

```
import { Document, Schema, Model, model} from "mongoose";

export interface IUser {
    name: string;
}
export interface IUserDocument extends IUser, Document {

}
export var UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    name: String,
});

export const User: Model<IUserDocument> = model<IUserDocument>("User", UserSchema);
```

> The code right above works properly on a node project (I tried by myself). I got it from: http://brianflove.com/2016/10/04/typescript-declaring-mongoose-schema-model/#schema--model
>   With the last export I create a model of type: `IUserDocument`.

I also modified the following two files:

**/src/pages/home/home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPromise } from '../../extras/social-media';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  test() {
    console.log('Hello World');
    LoginPromise('facebook').then(
      (name: string) => {
        console.log('### Social Media -> ' + name);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

**/src/pages/home/home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  <p>
    This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps
    that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>src/pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>

  <button ion-button (click)="test()" color="primary">Test</button>

</ion-content>
```

My problem, is that when I run:

```
$ ionic serve --no-open
```

I don't get any error on the console, but on the browser I get the following:

```
"Runtime Error: Object(...) is not a function"
```

as you can see here:

[image]

Do you have any idea about what could be going on here and how can I make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to resolve this already?

Answer (score 0):

> Runtime Error: Object(…) is not a function

Your call :

```
model<IUserDocument>("User", UserSchema);
```

is wrong. `model` is not a function. Its an object.

## Fix

Don't *invoke* an object. The code is wrong.

Comment: please, read the yellow note I just added underneath of that code snippet. I got the code from: http://brianflove.com/2016/10/04/typescript-declaring-mongoose-schema-model/#schema--model, I successfully tried that code on a `Node` project without any problem.

Comment: also, if I comment the `callMeIfYouNeedMe` block out on the file: `/src/extras/social-media.ts`, and leave the line: `export const User: Model<IUserDocument> = model<IUserDocument>("User", UserSchema);` as it is, then, there is no error. So, I think that line is not the problem. I just added that comment to my code above.